# Angular 2: Download any type of file

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I want to download any type of file, it can be PDF, Image, Excel etc, I want to make it dynamic, I have tried many ways but failed. The server sending me in `application/octet-stream` type  please help me out in this, below is the code to download file:

Note: File saved in the file system with the unique name and its real name stored in the database and associated with that unique name.

Server (Spring-Boot):

```
public class Media {
    private Integer id;
    private String uuid; // To store file on disk using unique name
    private String fileName;

    //Setter and getter
}

@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable("id") Integer id)
{
    Media media = mediaRepository.findOne(id);
    File file = new File("C:\\upload\\" + media.getUuid());
    Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
    ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + media.getFileName());

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                             .headers(headers)
                             .contentLength(file.length())
                             .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                             .body(byteArrayResource);
}
```

Angular 2:

```
downloadAnyFile(id) {
  this.fileService.download(id).subscribe((res) => {
    var blob = new Blob([res._body], { type: res.headers.get("Content-Type") });
    var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url, "_blank");
  });
}

download(id) {
  return this.http.get(Constants.BASE_URL + this.context + id)
         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. If you find any solution please post here..